# Squid proxy problems with DNS resolution

Tags: proxy, squid

I need to configure a proxy in Mozzilla Firefox to access some websites my organization blocks. Till now, i used a simple smartphone app called "Easy Proxy" that make a simple HTTP/HTTPS proxy in the local network and with this i can connect to these websites from my browser correctly (with the proxy configured).
Now, i want to setup a simple Squid Proxy in place of the smartphone app on a simple Raspberry to have the same result; i need to allow all the internet traffic without restrictions, so I edited the squid.conf file in this way:

```
http_port 3128

# Log Options (human readable)
#access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
logformat timereadable %tl %6tr %>a %Ss/%03Hs %<st %rm %ru %un %Sh/%<A %mt
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log timereadable

# allow all requests
#acl all src 0.0.0.0/0
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all

#DNS settings
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# Add CORS headers
reply_header_access Access-Control-Allow-Origin allow all
reply_header_replace Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
reply_header_access Access-Control-Allow-Methods allow all
reply_header_replace Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
reply_header_access Access-Control-Allow-Headers allow all
reply_header_replace Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
```

Unfortunatly, i have a lot of error with cross-origin requests blocked and i can't navigate on these websites correclty.
I think (but i don't know why) that the Firefox browser is still using my corporate DNS instead of the DNS i specified in the Squid configuration file because these errors are the same i get without the proxy configured.

I don't understand which could be the difference between my Squid proxy and the proxy i used as a smartphone app (Easy Proxy).
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot in advance
Christian